# MYSQL Event IF then run query

Tags: mysql, events, if-statement

What would be the proper way to do this? tried many things and searched everywhere online

```
CREATE EVENT myevent
ON SCHEDULE AT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 5 DAYS
DO
  BEGIN


SELECT CASE WHEN funded IS NULL OR funded = '' 
   THEN INSERT INTO mytable1 (`id`, `to`) VALUES (NULL, 'admin')
   ELSE 
FROM mytable2 WHERE id='$id';



  END
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
   DECLARE xFounded varchar(10);

  SELECT funded into xFounded  FROM mytable2 WHERE id='$id';

  if xFounded  is null or xFounded  ='' then

   INSERT INTO mytable1 (`id`, `to`) VALUES (NULL, 'admin');
   ELSE 
  // Do Else Part Here

  end if;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably the shorest way.

```
insert into mytable1 (`id`, `to`) VALUES (NULL, 'admin') on duplicate key update id=LAST_INSERT_ID(id), to=to;
select LAST_INSERT_ID();
```